# LLVM command line on OSX

Tags: macos, llvm

I'm working though [http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html][1], trying to write a very simple pass. I've written the pass and compiled it (thanks in part to the Stackoverflow community) but now I'm having trouble running it...

The documentation reads:

> To test it, follow the example at the end of the Getting Started Guide
>   to compile "Hello World" to LLVM. We can now run the bitcode file
>   (hello.bc) for the program through our transformation like this (or
>   course, any bitcode file will work):
>
> $ opt -load ../../../Debug+Asserts/lib/Hello.so -hello < hello.bc >
>   /dev/null Hello: __main Hello: puts Hello: main The '-load' option
>   specifies that 'opt' should load your pass as a shared object, which
>   makes '-hello' a valid command line argument (which is one reason you
>   need to register your pass). Because the hello pass does not modify
>   the program in any interesting way, we just throw away the result of
>   opt (sending it to /dev/null).

However when I run the command I get the following issue:

```
mymachine$./opt -load ../../../Debug+Asserts/lib/Hello.so -hello < hello.bc > /dev/null 
Error opening '../../../Debug+Asserts/lib/Hello.so': 
   dlopen(../../../Debug+Asserts/lib/Hello.so, 9): image not found  
   -load request ignored. opt: Unknown command line argument '-hello'.  
Try: './opt -help' opt: Did you mean '-help'?
```

Any ideas? I'm running OSX and I suspect that is part of the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the the command I wanted (from the bin directory) was:

```
opt  -load ../lib/LLVMHello.dylib -hello < hello.bc > /dev/null
```

and I understand the .dylib is the OSX equivalent of .so - but this was largely guesswork...

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path rather than a relative one?  This seems like a relatively obvious "file not found".